# Why rev commad is not working inside the shell script

Tags: unix

I wrote a script to reverse the string using the rev command.

```
#!bin/bash

Var1="string"
Var2="`rev $Var1`"
echo $Var2
```

Why it is not working, please help me with this problem.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is wrong.  You need to [capture the output of a command](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution):

```
Var2=$(rev <<< "$Var1")
```

The `<<<` syntax is referred to as [here strings](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings).

Comment: Here strings are not available in POSIX `sh` and legacy shells, though.

Answer (score 1):

`rev` receives filenames as arguments, or read from standard input.

```
$ var1="string"
$ var2="`echo "$var1" | rev`"
$ echo "$var2"
gnirts
```